# How to switch blender 3d render source from video editing back to 3D scene camera

Tags: edit-mode, camera, video, scene

[image]
After I switch from the 3D scene to the video editing mode, my F12 rendering always outputs the video image. Will the rendering result be switched back to the 3D model rendering mode after the video editing mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do one of two things:

1. Remove the video strips from the VSE, which I assume yo don't want to do; or
2. Go to the *Post Processing* panel in the *Output Properties* tab in the Properties editor and disable *Sequencer* by unchecking it:

[image: Post Processing panel of Output Properties tab of the properties editor showing sequencer option]

Comment: Thank you so much! It work!

Comment: You're welcome.  Be warned though.  Eventually you'll want the VSE for a video strip and have fogotten this.  Happens to all of us.